# Getting Operating System Username using MySQL SQLi

Tags: ssh, sql-injection, mysql, kali-linux, ubuntu

Suppose I have a website which has SQL injection vulnerability and I got the database schema etc. Is there any means by which I can get the operating system username or the SSH username?

Asking from hardening purpose

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the permissions given to the database user who you are acting as. If they have command execution privileges, it would be possible to use those to run a command such as `id`. Without that privilege, though, it is not supposed to be possible, but could be if the MySQL user was also a valid system user. In that case, it is possible to obtain the MySQL user through the `user()` function, which could then be used on the system, although these would not be the same entity (e.g. they could have distinct passwords)

Comment: user privilege is USAGE